# Connecting Atmel AVRISP to JTAGICE header

Tags: avr, atmel, jtag, avrdude, isp

I have an AVR board with [10-pin JTAGICE](http://www.atmel.com/tools/AVRJTAGICEMKII.aspx) header and a [6-pin ISP](http://www.atmel.com/tools/AVRISPMKII.aspx). Can I somehow connect the ISP to program this board without having JTAG functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to tell what specific controller you use, but as far as I know, the AVRs never share the same pins for JTAG and ISP. Those are fundamentally different interfaces.